# How to write this Regular Expression for this situation?

Tags: regex

I want to get the input String splitted by a colon. For example, `a:int`. I can use `[^:]*` to get the `a` and `int`.

However, I don't want the String to be split by any combination which includes colon, such as `A:=3:command`. What I want are the `A:=3` and `command` but not `A`, `=3`, `command`.

Could someone tell me how to write the regular expression?

Comment: This is awfully localized and not likely to be useful to many people. Voting to close.

Comment: So which colons are okay to split on and which are not?  You should colons followed by equal signs are not to be split on, but are there other situations where your colon is non-splittable?  Can you qualify exactly the conditions you have in mind?

Comment: How does your split function work? Your first regex will match any non-colon characters. If I split the string i will get only colons...

Comment: The question as titled is worthy of closing, but if it were retitled to something like "Splitting a string on characters only in a specific context" then it probably _is_ useful, since a good solution will use lookahead in the split regex.

Comment: @matcauthon - the OP is probably using `match`, not `split` - the result here is similar, barring a few edge cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume, pending an edit by the OP, that the only colons that should appear in a split are those followed by simple ASCII letters or numbers.  The solution can easily be generalized.

Here is a concrete example in JavaScript:

```
s = "x:=3:comment"
s.split(/:(?=[\s\w])/)
```

The result is

```
['x:=3','comment']
```

The split function says "split on colons that are followed by spaces or word characters (ASCII letters or numbers or underscores)".

Other languages have more powerful forms of lookaround (in particular negative lookarounds), but the basic idea is to construct a regex where the split value is a colon *in a particular context*.

**ADDENDUM**

Another example:

```
"this:has:(some%:   7colons:$:6)".split(/:(?=[\s\w])/)
```

produces:

```
['this','has:(some%','   7colons:$','6')]
```

Answer (score 1):

On the face of it, you want to split on the last colon in the string, so you want the trailing material to be a string of non-colons, and the preceding material to be anything.  You also didn't specify (at the time I answered the question) which sub-species of regex you want (which language you are writing in), so you get Perl for my answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ( "a:int", "A:=3:comment" );

foreach my $item (@array)
{
    my($prefix, $suffix) = $item =~ m/^(.*):([^:]+)$/;
    print "$prefix and $suffix\n";
}
```

The output from that script is:

```
a and int
A:=3 and comment
```

Clearly, if the rule for the split is different (it isn't simply 'the last colon'), then the pattern will have to change.  But this achieves the stated requirements reasonably cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ray's answer, another option is to white-list the operators you support, for example, to support `:=` (JavaScript example):

```
var s = "hello:world:=5:and:r";
var tokens = s.match(/(?:[^:]|:=)+/g);
```

For example, if you want the operators `:=`, `=:`, `:=:` and `::`, you could write:

```
/(?:[^:]|:=|=:|:=:|::)+/g
```

(this can be simplified to, but I think it's easily maintainable).